# How to use global providers in the Next.js App Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the classic Pages Router of Next, You can add a global provider in your `_app.js` file and wrap it around the entire component tree. This will ensure that the provider is available to all components.

If you do this using the App Router, you get an error message

> You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.

Is there a way to achieve something similar without giving up the Server Components?

Comment: Hi Farouk! Please go through the answer of the linked thread. You will get an answer, while the questions are slightly different.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the provider in a client component.

```js
'use client';
 
import { SomeProvider } from 'some-library';
 
export function Providers({ children }) {
  return (
    <SomeProvider>
      {children}
    </SomeProvider>
  );
}
```

And use this wrapped provider in root layout.

```js
import { Providers } from './providers';
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: useContext will make the entire compoennt client side as well. i'm looking for something that can be used for server compoennts as well.

Comment: Worth noting that this is the [recommended approach](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#rendering-third-party-context-providers-in-server-components) in the docs

Comment: Looks like the link has been moved to here: https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs#rendering-third-party-context-providers-in-server-components

Comment: According to the next.js docs

"With the provider rendered at the root, all other Client Components throughout your app will be able to consume this context."

So, I have tested that, server components still render only on the server side, next.js optimizes it automatically

Answer (score -2):

// use context in _app.js

// user.js

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(true);

  const exposed = {
    user,
  };

  return <Context.Provider value={exposed}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

export const useUser = () => useContext(Context);

export default Provider;
```

// _app.js

```
import UserProvider from "../context/user";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <UserProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </UserProvider>
    );
}
export default MyApp;
```

// use user state in any component like this

```
import { useUser } from "../context/user";

export default function Home({ lessons }) {
  const { user } = useUser();
  console.log({ user });
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```